# How does one utilize the apply function over columns of an xts object?

Tags: r, xts

I have the below xts object in R and am trying to compute the max over the last three columns (b,c & d)for each row.  The first row can produce an NA.

```
library(xts)

    x <-  structure(c(3.081786, 3.001786, 3.063214, 3.07, 3.0875, 
0.167143, 0.0760719999999999, 0.0642850000000004, 0.0446430000000002, 
0.279643, NA, 0.0767860000000002, 0.019285, 0.0528569999999999, 0.268214, 
NA, 0.000714000000000325, 0.0450000000000004, 0.00821399999999972, 
0.0114290000000001), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", 
.indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = 
structure(1615250183.87979, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), index = 
structure(c(1167782400, 1167868800, 1167955200, 1168214400, 1168300800), 
tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = 5:4, .Dimnames = list( NULL, 
c("a", "b", "c", "d")))


>x

                  a        b        c        d
2007-01-03 3.081786 0.167143       NA       NA
2007-01-04 3.001786 0.076072 0.076786 0.000714
2007-01-05 3.063214 0.064285 0.019285 0.045000
2007-01-08 3.070000 0.044643 0.052857 0.008214
2007-01-09 3.087500 0.279643 0.268214 0.011429
```

I thought the below would work but it doesn't produce the desired result and also has the unintended consequence of producing duplicate rows.

```
x$e <- apply(x[,2:4],1,max)
> x

                  a        b        c        d        e
2007-01-03 3.081786 0.167143       NA       NA       NA
2007-01-03       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
2007-01-04 3.001786 0.076072 0.076786 0.000714       NA
2007-01-04       NA       NA       NA       NA 0.076786
2007-01-05 3.063214 0.064285 0.019285 0.045000       NA
2007-01-05       NA       NA       NA       NA 0.064285
2007-01-08 3.070000 0.044643 0.052857 0.008214       NA
2007-01-08       NA       NA       NA       NA 0.052857
2007-01-09 3.087500 0.279643 0.268214 0.011429       NA
2007-01-09       NA       NA       NA       NA 0.279643
```

Two questions:

1. What is the correct way to compute the max over the last three columns for each row without producing duplicate rows?
2. Why are duplicate rows produced when executing `apply(y[,2:4],1,max))`?

Comment: Works for me - `x$e <- apply(x[,2:4],1,max)` can you provide exactly the structure of `x` via `dput(x)` ?

Comment: >dput(x)
structure(c(3.081786, 3.001786, 3.063214, 3.07, 3.0875, 0.167143, 
0.0760719999999999, 0.0642850000000004, 0.0446430000000002, 0.279643, 
NA, 0.0767860000000002, 0.019285, 0.0528569999999999, 0.268214, 
NA, 0.000714000000000325, 0.0450000000000004, 0.00821399999999972, 
0.0114290000000001), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1615250183.87979, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), index = structure(c(1167782400, 1167868800, 1167955200, 
1168214400, 1168300800), tzone = "UTC", tclass =

Comment: "Date"), .Dim = 5:4, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("a", "b", "c", "d")))

Comment: Looks to be something funny with the fact that `apply` results in a named vector - `x$e <- unname(apply(x[,2:4], 1, max))` works for instance.

Comment: For me rows do not duplicate. Number of rows remain the same. Are you sure your `dput` is correct though? For me row numbers are like numbers `1167782400`, `1167868800` and there are of lot of attributes printed when I type `x` in the console.

Comment: @RonakShah - here's a minimal example - `library(xts); x <- xts(matrix(1:6,nrow=3,dimnames=list(NULL,letters[1:2])), order.by=Sys.Date() + 0:2); x$c <- apply(x, 1, max)`

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with `matrixStats::rowMaxs` which works and is more efficient.

```
x$e <- matrixStats::rowMaxs(x, cols=2:4, na.rm=T)
x
#                   a        b        c        d        e
# 2007-01-03 3.081786 0.167143       NA       NA 0.167143
# 2007-01-04 3.001786 0.076072 0.076786 0.000714 0.076786
# 2007-01-05 3.063214 0.064285 0.019285 0.045000 0.064285
# 2007-01-08 3.070000 0.044643 0.052857 0.008214 0.052857
# 2007-01-09 3.087500 0.279643 0.268214 0.011429 0.279643
```

Where:

```
class(x)
# [1] "xts" "zoo"
```

Comment: FYI, `matrixStats::rowMaxs(x, cols=2:4, na.rm=TRUE)` is more efficient than `matrixStats::rowMaxs(x[, 2:4], na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @HenrikB Wow, indeed around 70% faster, I am impressed!

Comment: There's a simple reason: `x[, 2:4]` requires temporarily allocating memory for a new object of that size and copying the values over, and later having the garbage collector clean up, whereas using `cols=2:4` operates directly on the existing three columns without the extra overhead.

Comment: @HenrikB I thought something like this.Thanks for the insight!